# Equivalent of gtk.window_set_default_icon in gtk3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I am trying to convert a python2 pyGTK program ([Comix](http://comix.sourceforge.net/)) to GTK3 python3 program.

I am not really familiar with GTK also for what does this mean about my understanding of the original program's logic. Anyway I have found a point where this function appears:

```
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(os.path.join(icon_path, '16x16/comix.png'))
gtk.window_set_default_icon(pixbuf)
```

and it throws an error reporting:

> AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute
>   'window_set_default_icon'

I have tried to find the equivalent function in GTK3 but to no avail. The function that causes the problem is the latter one (`gtk.window_set_default_icon()`).

So, how can I write this snippet in GTK3 in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the function call. It is actually the window you call the function on. Example:

```
window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_icon(pixbuf)
```

Comment: Yeah you are right although I did not write the above code so in pyGTK it should have been possible to set it to the `gtk` module directly I guess.